# .Net Core 3.0 AJAX POST Body Always Null

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, unobtrusive-ajax

I've recently converted my project from .Net Framework 4.7 to .Net Core 3.0.  I'm having trouble getting my AJAX post to work.

**Here is what's working in .Net Framework 4.7:**

View:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Save", "Controller", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "Post", OnSuccess = "OnSaveSuccess", OnFailure = "OnFailure" }, new { Model }))
{
  ... Model Code Here
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Save(Contract contract)
```

**Here's what is not working in .Net Core 3.0:**

View:

```
<form method="post" action="/Controller/Save" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="post" data-ajax-sucess="OnSaveSuccess"  data-ajax-failure="OnFailure">
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Save([FromBody] Contract contract)
```

The Contract object comes as NULL in this request.  Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being my fault.  I had put:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
   contentType: "application/json"
});
```

This was causing the POST to not map properly.  Once I removed it the Model came over correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the following example to perform ajax submission using jQuery Unobtrusive AJAX.

```
<form method="post" action="/Home/Save" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="post" data-ajax-success="OnSaveSuccess" data-ajax-failure="OnFailure">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label asp-for="Name" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
            <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label asp-for="Email" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
            <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-7 offset-sm-3">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

*obtain and reference jquery-ajax-unobtrusive*

```
@section scripts{
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive/dist/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
    <script>
        function OnSaveSuccess(res) {
            console.log(res);
            alert('Success');
        }

        function OnFailure() {
             alert('failed');
        }
    </script>
}
```

*Contract class*

```
public class Contract
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

*Controller Action (with [FromForm] attribute)*

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Save([FromForm] Contract contract)
{
    // code logic here
}
```

*Test Result*

[image]