# Empty arguments Ajax ASP.NET Core 3.0 MVC

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using an ASP.NET Core 3.0 MVC application in which I make the following jQuery Ajax call:

```
return $.ajax({
    type: type,
    url: '/' + controller + '/' + action,
    data: jsonData,
    timeout: timeout,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (returnedData) {
        successFunc(returnedData);
    },
    error: function (errMsg) {
        errorFunc(errMsg);
    }
});
```

passing it the data object

```
{
  input1: 'random',
  input2: '1',
  input3: '1',
},
```

But it always passes null arguments through:

[image: Null arguments from Ajax call]

I have also tried adding addnewtonsoftjson() in startup but it doesn't seem to change anything.

A similar question here, doesn't really have an answer:
[.Net Core 3.0 AJAX POST Body Always Null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60104144/net-core-3-0-ajax-post-body-always-null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error seems to com from defining the content type.

```
   return $.ajax({
        type: type,

        url: '/' + controller + '/' + action,
        data: jsonData,

        success: function (returnedData) {
            successFunc(returnedData);
        },
        error: function (errMsg) {
            errorFunc(errMsg);
        }
    });
```

has no *contentType* defined and passes through to the action in the controller correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is kinda relative to the HTTP method/type you are using and the contentType you are passing to the backend.

I've found a great summary of contentType [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60252001/9884676)

If you don't wanna dive too deep into this you could change your contentType into `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8` should resolve your problem

Comment: I used   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", changed the type to GET and removed the JSON.stringify and this now works. Seemingly i don't understand AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

So keep the c# code as you have shown in your question. 
In you js call:

```
var data = JSON.stringify({ 
                 'input1': ‘inputvalue’,
                 'input2':’inputvalue’,
                 ‘input3’: ‘inputval’
               });

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: same as you have in the question
        data: data,

        contentType: 'application/json',

success: function (returnedData) {
        successFunc(returnedData);
    },
    error: function (errMsg) {
        errorFunc(errMsg);
    }

    });
```

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't change it. Still null.

Comment: I think your data is not in correct format. Can you try changing you parameter from three strings to just “JObject data”. If that works and you see you data variable with some values then either you use this and extract the strings from here or you reformat you data that you are posting from ajax

Comment: The literal string? "JObject Data"?

Comment: The type string to type JObject.

Comment: I've changed it all so much I can't even get it to successfully call the back end. Do you have a working example?

Comment: Okay let’s take a step back. Updated my answer, follow that and let me know what you find.

Comment: @user11917447 check my answer now.

Comment: I tried your solution, still no luck. I removed contentType and it worked.